# How to create a dialog using jquery

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am basically trying to achieve what this [page](http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/) has:

When clicked on an image, it should pop out, make the back screen black, and have a close button.

I've seen lot of sites with this.  Does anyone know which jquery plugin could be used for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a comparison of 10 different implementations:

http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts

Answer (score 1):

Here's one but I'd recommend you just search the plugins on the jQuery site or bang your question into Google and look for the perfect one for your needs, there's gadgillions out there!

[jQuery lightbox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a jquery ui plugin for modals: http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/

Comment: You might want to add some clarification around that link.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [jQuery UI Dialog Plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), to stick with jQuery, and putting an img inside the content to show.

By the way, the page is using [Lightview](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/), wich works with Prototype and Scriptaculous (but not jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) or [lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) for images

Answer (score 0):

facebox is good too... I've been using that one, and it works well.
Though if you're using it with ASP.NET you need to make a small change to the js file. 
(Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162276/jquery-facebox-plugin-get-it-inside-the-form-tag)).

Also, you would need to make a small css change (or possibly js) to get the blackened background, but it wouldn't be too hard.