# window.opener & facebox

Tags: javascript, facebox, window.opener

I opened a window in facebox. Now, I want to send some data to the opening window
when the facebox window closes. I know how to do this with a normal pop-up but not with facebox and there doesn't seem to be much in the way of good documentation here.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162276/jquery-facebox-plugin-get-it-inside-the-form-tag

Answer (score -1):

The only way to "send some data to the opening window" is to use the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) method of the window (or you could change the window's `name` property, but this is being removed from future versions of Firefox). You would want to use `window.opener && window.opener.postMessage(your_message, facebook_origin)`. If you meant "send some data to Facebook", you would want to use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XmlHttpRequest) to a same-origin proxy or use a cross-domain request if Facebook allows it.

Edit: Sorry, I misread Facebox as Facebook, which is an external site.

Comment: Thanks for your response but Jordan is correct. I am trying to figure out how to close a facbox (jquery plugin) winodw and send data back to the opening window.